# C# - Multi Select List Box changing values

Tags: c#, listbox, multi-select

I have some strings in a multi select box, and every time a user selects a value it'll update accordingly like so:

```
     if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            special1.Price = 18;

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {

            special1.Price = 25;

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            special1.Price = 40;

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            special1.Price = 30;

        }
```

and that works fine for me, but how can I make it so that if a user selects more than 1 value from the listbox that the Special1.Price stores each value separately? I find that when I try to select 2 or more, the values get overwritten by the last selected one.

The Price property is just a simple get and set.

Thanks

Comment: ...make Price an array or `List` that can actually handle multiple values? Also, you may want to use a [switch statement](http://goo.gl/f0Yh2).

Comment: Change the listbox' SelectionMode property to "One".  Because allowing the user to select more than one item doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To loop through all selected items in a listbox you should use SelectedIndices, which is a collection of the zero based index of the selected items.

I have if-else if... with an array names prices, it is much easier to write and much better to extend if needed (if lstSpecial contains more than 4 items you may need a check to avoid boundary failure.).

```
const int[] prices = new int[]{18,25,40,30};
int total = 0;
foreach(int index in lstSpecial.SelectedIndices)
    total += prices[index];
special1.Price = total;
```

Answer (score 0):

Price is a property as you said , probably of type int. It can only hold one value at a time. If you want to hold multiple values, you need to use a collection. You can declare price as a list and then you would be able to add each price on your if statement. Something on the following line. 
Declare your Price property like:

```
public List<int> Price {get;set;}
```

Then:(Its better to use switch in the following scenario)

```
if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            special1.Price.Add(18);

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {

            special1.Price.Add(25);

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            special1.Price.Add(40);

        }
        else if (lstSpecial.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            special1.Price.Add(30);

        }
```

This way you will have all the selected prices. You can check them using:

```
foreach(int p in special1.Price)
{
Console.WriteLine(p);
}
```

I am not sure about your class structure, but if special class represents a single Item, then its better to have a collection of 'Special' and then add price for each of them